# Can I initiative a re-crawl / re-index of my Bing Custom Search site?

Tags: bing-api, azure-cognitive-services, bing-custom-search

I am trying to get Bing to re-crawl / re-index our site after we have added some new "search." meta tags and need those to show up in our Bing Custom Search results.

I have tried using the Bing Webmaster Tools and Submit URLs under Configure My Site, however, no re-crawling has occurred in over a day.

The last site crawl dates are just getting reporting as older and as far back as 5/15/2019.

Is there a way to accomplish this or are we just stuck waiting?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-custom-search/define-your-custom-view) states:

> All domains, subpages, and webpages that you specify must be public and indexed by Bing. If you own a public site that you want to include in the search, and Bing hasn’t indexed it, see the Bing webmaster documentation for details about getting Bing to index it. Also, see the webmaster documentation for details about getting Bing to update your crawled site if the index is out of date.

So, it appears that the controls for re-crawling are solely those in the webmaster tools.